# Where can I find resources of the biological processes occurring after death of a mammal at various temperatures?

Tags: biochemistry, death, temperature

Using google I usually end with results in cell death. I found some layman articles, but that does not help.
My main interest is the brain part.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [William Bass](https://anthropology.utk.edu/people/william-m-bass-iii/) has written on this, probably in the [Journal of Forensic Sciences](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/15564029), but no specific articles come to mind. I'd start by looking for his articles, then probably with a variety of search terms using a filter for that journal. It's not open access, so you'll need to use a library or institution that has a subscription.